# spring boot static html not displaying model data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my `Controller` I am returning the `model` object like below:

```
----
modelAndView.addObject("confirmMessage",
            "User is successfully registered. Please follow the instructions sent to your email for activation.");
modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/success.html");
        return modelAndView;
```

I have `success.html` file inside the `static` directory. The file is loaded but the stylesheet is not getting loaded.

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <!-- include css in the header -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1>
        <!-- include image from static resources -->
        Adding Static Resources (css, JavaScript, Images) to Thymeleaf
    </h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have configured webjar as dependency in pom.xml file and for all the thymeleaf templates under the resources directory, the bootstrap file is loaded but not for this page. I am not even able to fetch the data that I added in the model object.

I added a configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(
                "/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations(
                        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/",
                        "classpath:/static/");
    }

}
```

After adding the above, I am getting `404` error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The answer is in the title of your question: it's a **static** html page. Not a dynamic thymeleaf template. So all your thymeleaf tags are never interpreted.

Comment: And even if it was a dynamic template, you wouldn't be able to display the model since you **redirect** to the template rather than forwarding to it. A redirect tells the browser to send a new request to a different URL. So everything you store in the current request is useless.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The issue that is confusing is, why I get 404 error, when I add WebConfig configuration.  Can you please explain this.

Comment: Probably because you've added `EnableWebMvc`, which removes **all** the MVC configuration done by Spring Boot. Don't ever use EnableWebMvc in Spring Boot. And you don't need to do anything for webjars to be supported: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content